# Remove substring from string, where only the beginning and end of the string are known

Tags: php

I have a variable in my PHP code where its equal to a stored string.
A small portion of this string is taken and used as a preview on a different page.
On occasion there will be Javascript in that string, how could I say the following:

```
Pseudocode:
if stringVar contains "<script"
then remove the substring starting at "<script" and ending at "/script>"
```

Comment: Are you sure that within that text, you will _NEVER_ find another instance of "<script", or "/script>" before the actual ends? If you are, it sounds like this would be trivial to do with a regex replace. P.S. This sounds suspiciously like trying to [parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/540162) - if that's the case, don't do it; use an XML parser instead.

Comment: Are you by chance looking for [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/strip_tags)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just getting rid of script tags:

```
$result = preg_replace('%<script>.*</script>%i', '', $subject);
```

Answer (score 0):

strpos function returns the position of one string in another,

```
so your start is strpos($SomeString,"<script")

end is strpos($SomeString,"/script>") + 7
```

after that it's just substr to get     everything before and after.

```
Note this will not work if <script can contains the <Script /Script> tags...
```